# Python как добавлять значения в словарь, без удаления предыдущего значения?

Tags: python, sqlite, словари

Мой код берет данные из БД, разделяет по марки и модели, и после для каждой модели подбирает свою марку. Но проблема в том, что последующее значение, удаляет предыдущее, как сохранить их все?

Вот БД

| car | model |
| --- | --- |
| Hava | mx1 |
| Haval | xx100 |
| BMW | X5 |
| BMW | X6 |
| BMW | X3 |
| Mersedes | Q2 |
| Mersedes | Q1 |
| Mersedes | M3 |
| Mersedes | MM14 |
| Mersedes | hh1 |
| Lada | Kalina |
| Lada | Kalina |
| Audi | a8 |
| Cherry | GS21 |
| Mersedes | hh1 |
| Mersedes | Sclass |

```
    class db_info:

    def take_info_from_db(self=None):
        key_colum =[]
        car_dicts ={}
        models = []
        for first_col in cursor.fetchall():
            key_colum.append(first_col[0])
            key_colum.append(first_col[1])
            if key_colum[1] not in car_dicts:
                car_dicts[str(key_colum[0])] = key_colum[1]
                key_colum.pop(0)
                key_colum.pop(0)

        car_dicts={key:[value] for key, value in car_dicts.items()}

        print(car_dicts)

db = db_info
print(db.take_info_from_db())
```

И на выход получаю это. Все бы хорошо, но в словарь сохраняется только последняя модель для определенной марки. Как исправить?

> {'Haval': ['xx100'], 'BMW': ['X3'], 'Mersedes': ['Sclass'], 'Lada': ['Kalina'], 'Audi': ['a8'], 'Cherry': ['GS21']}

Comment: а что должно быть на выходе? Вижу в таблице кучу моделей мерседеса (пишется, кстати, Mer**c**edes). Что должно быть в итоговом словаре для этой марки?

Comment: Ну, для начала в словаре модели привязываются к марке, и например в выпадающем списке, когда выбирается какая- то марка, в соседнем списке будут варианты с моделями только этой марки. Пока все встало на том- что в словаре значения заменяют предыдущие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы так заполнял словарь:

```
car_by_models = dict()

for car, model in cursor.fetchall():
    if car not in car_by_models:
        car_by_models[car] = []
    car_by_models[car].append(model)

print(car_by_models)
```

Вариант без распаковки полей в цикле:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    car = row[0]
    model = row[1]
    if car not in car_by_models:
        car_by_models[car] = []
    car_by_models[car].append(model)

print(car_by_models)
```

Если использовать `defaultdict`, то можно без проверок:

```
from collections import defaultdict
...

car_by_models = defaultdict(list)

for car, model in cursor.fetchall():
    car_by_models[car].append(model)

print(car_by_models)
```

Comment: можно просто .setdefault - без collections

Comment: @splash58, ну да, но мне почему-то setdefault не нравится, им не пользуюсь, поэтому забываю про него :)

Comment: Пытаюсь, выдает ошибку **too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Comment: @АлександрКузнецов, значит в `cursor.fetchall()` у вас больше 2 элементов возвращается SELECT'ом. Добавил в ответ еще вариант без распаковки элементов в цикле

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрКузнецов, пожалуйста :)