# Помогите с словарем списков

Tags: python

Есть excel файл, в виде:

```
Номер телефона, Номер дисконт карты, ФИО, Бонусы.
```

Скажите, как с этого файла сделать:

```
bonuses={
         Номер телефона:[Номер дисконт карты, Бонусы, ФИО], 
         Номер телефона:[Номер дисконт карты, Бонусы, ФИО], итд.
}
```

Comment: Я бы так предложил: `Номер телефона: [[Номер дисконт карты, Бонусы, ФИО], [Номер дисконт карты, Бонусы, ФИО], итд.]`, тут значением будет список списков. Можно сделать по аналогии с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1418986/201445

Comment: Не совсем понятно почему на один номер телефона словарь с вложенными списками. Возможно нужен словарь с ключами из номеров и значениями в виде списка? Если да, то метод "setdefault" поможет.

Comment: А можете, написать код, Спс

Comment: исправил, сорри

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант следующий. Пройти циклом for, по Вашему файлу:

```
bonuses = {}

for data in 'excel file':
# в data будет строка из вашей таблицы, с типом данных, которые можно итерировать,
# и с которым можно работать срезами и обращаться по индексам
    bonuses.setdefault(data[0], []).append(','.join([c for c in data[1:]]))
```

Результат на каждой итерации:

```
{'номер телефона': ['номер карты,бонус,ФИО']}
```

Так правда неудобно будет работать с полученными данными, но всё зависит от того, что с ними дальше делать.

Альтернативный вариант:

```
bonuses = {}

for data in 'excel file':
    bonuses.setdefault(data[0], [])
    bonuses[data[0]].append(data[1])
    bonuses[data[0]].append(data[2])
    bonuses[data[0]].append(data[3])
```

Результат.

```
{'номер телефона': [1254, 'бонус', 'ФИО']}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @bestmovieclips пожалуйста. Если Вам помог ответ, можете отметить его как верный=).

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но не знаю как

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer  что-то вроде этого=)

Answer (score 1):

еще как вариант можно использовать pandas, он и excel файл заодно прочитает. вот что-то вроде этого:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col=0)
bonuses = df.apply(list,1).to_dict()
```

как в pandas прочесть excel можно посмотреть в [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)

Comment: код у меня стал: ' "998905888375" ': [' "1153" ', '"69560"', 'Meliboyev Akmaljon']". Как мне убрать из 998905888375 и 1153 парные кавычки. Спасибо.